# Cat redirection not working

Tags: command-line, bash, cat

I used a command

```
set -r noclobber
```

Now I'm not able to reset. `cat >1.txt` shows `Restricted: can't redirect output`

Comment: If you want to reset this, use the following command: `set +C` You find an explanation, when you run the command `help set`

Comment: I see no `-r` option in `help set`. What is that supposed to do? And I hope you are not trying to run `cat >1.txt` (sic), since it gives nothing to `cat`. [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: @Quasímodo `set -r` will put the shell in restricted mode I think (equivalent to starting it as `rbash`). Personally I find the `cat >1.txt` construct handy for file input (it's a kind of on-the-fly heredoc). Once in restricted mode I don't think there's a way out short of starting a new shell.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for that, I would never have realized how useful that `cat>file` could be! But still think that info would be good up there in the question.

Comment: @Quasímodo you're right though, the `set` section of `man bash` doesn't appear to mention `r`, although conversely the `OPTIONS` section (which includes command line swith `-r`) mentions that all the single-character `set` options may be used as command-line options... puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be listed under the `set` builtin, but `set -r` appears to have the same effect as invoking `bash` with the `-r` command line option: that is, as documented under `OPTIONS`

> ```
>    -r        If  the  -r  option  is present, the shell becomes restricted
>              (see RESTRICTED SHELL below).
> ```

Under `RESTRICTED SHELL` you will see

> ```
> RESTRICTED SHELL
>        If bash is started with the name rbash, or the -r option is supplied at
>        invocation, the shell becomes restricted.  A restricted shell  is  used
>        to  set  up an environment more controlled than the standard shell.  It
>        behaves identically to bash with the exception that the  following  are
>        disallowed or not performed:
> ```

One of the restrictions is

> ```
>    ·      redirecting output using the >, >|, <>, >&, &>, and >> redirect‐
>           ion operators
> ```

which explains why you are seeing `Restricted: can't redirect output`.

Normally, when an option is set with `set -`, it can be toggled off with an equivalent `set +`. However as you might expect, one of the things restricted by `RESTRICTED SHELL` mode is

> ```
>    ·      turning off restricted mode with set +r or set +o restricted.
> ```

So, as far as I know your only option will be to start a new, non-restricted shell.

---

The `set -o noclobber` option (or equivalently `set -C`) also affects redirection, but unlike `-r` only when the target file exists:

> ```
>           -C      If set, bash does not overwrite an  existing  file  with
>                   the  >,  >&,  and <> redirection operators.  This may be
>                   overridden when creating output files by using the redi‐
>                   rection operator >| instead of >.
> ```

Also unlike `-r`, this *is* toggleable using `set +C` (or `set +o noclobber`).